# Related List on Account Object for Child Accounts

Tags: account, related-list, childrecords

The standard parent account field does not provide a related list like most other relationship fields do. Per Salesforce's documentation and ideas on the idea exchange, this [isn't possible out of the box](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfgJUAR/view-child-accounts-on-parent-account-page). So the question is:

**How can one create a related list on the account record page to show child accounts?**

Rob's suggestion in that article is one option, but wondering what else others have done.

Answer (score 0):

The simple workaround I used (which in my mind is simpler than Rob's method) is as follows:

1. Create a custom field called "Parent Account (Custom)" or something like that
2. When creating the field, I called the related list "Child Accounts" or similar
3. Create a simple record triggered flow to update this field any time the parent account of an account is updated
4. Add the Child Accounts related list for the new custom field to the
   account record page

Some considerations with this:

1. This will work for any future updates, but obviously I'd have to retroactively update existing records. In my case I'm working on a new app, so this is a non-issue
2. I'd want to make sure this field isnt editable by anyone manually, otherwise it might throw off the perfect match between the parent account and the value of the new custom field
3. Related to point above, in fact it would be best to never even display this field to anyone (though they do need read only access to see related list)
4. It does create additional work to set up, but it is fairly simple, and the automation should be fairly straightforward and reliable